# Рекурсия при установке значения в объект

Tags: python, python-3.x

Занимаюсь написанием собственного объекта для хранения данных. В нём вместо обычной записи в `self.__dict__` я использую `self.__local_dict__`, для работы с которой перегружаю стандартные операторы класса.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__localDict__ = {}
        self.__localDict__.update(kwargs)

    #: Получение атрибута из объекта
    def __getattr__(self, name):    return self.__localDict__[name]

    #: Добавить атрибут в объект
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):    self.__localDict__.update({name:value})
    ...
```

Если же для `__getattr__` можно использовать следующее решение:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name in self.__dict__:
        if type(self.__dict__[name]) is function:
            return self.__dict__[name]
    else:   return self.__localDict__[name]
```

то для `__setattr__` я не знаю решения. :(

`def __setattr__(self, name, value):    self.__localDict__.update({name:value})` создаёт ошибку рекурсии функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в `__setattr__` выполнять проверку имени атрибута. Ошибка довольно тонкая, т.к. в обработчике обновления атрибута вы обновляете один из атрибутов, что и вправду порождает рекурсию.

```py
...

def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name != '__localDict__':
        self.__localDict__.update({name:value})

...
```

---

Дело, к слову, не в том, какой словарь используется для хранения атрибутов. Рекурсия в этом методе - частый гость. [Вот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020115) на подобный вопрос на EnSO.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!